# PDF image positioning

Tags: pdf

Considering following operator sequence:

```
    q
    0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0 cm
    1 g
    472 471.922 4014 6073 re
    f
    0 G
    0 g
    q
    8.33333 0 0 8.33333 0 0 cm
    BT
    /R7 12 Tf
    0 1.00055 -1 0 71.52 336.711 Tm
    [text 1] TJ
    /R8 9.96 Tf
    0 1.00057 -1 0 105.12 60.3506 Tm
    [text 2] TJ
    ET
    Q
    885 502.922 6 297 re
    f
    q
    8.33333 0 0 8.33333 0 0 cm
    BT
    /R8 9.96 Tf
    0 1.00057 -1 0 105.12 95.9906 Tm
    [text 3] TJ
    0 1.00057 -1 0 116.16 60.3505 Tm
    [text 4] TJ
    ET
    Q
    977 502.922 6 535 re
    f
    q
    8.33333 0 0 8.33333 0 0 cm
    BT
    /R8 9.96 Tf
    0 1.00057 -1 0 116.16 124.551 Tm
    [text 5] TJ
    0 1.00057 -1 0 127.2 60.3507 Tm
    [text 6] TJ
    ET
    Q
    1069 502.922 6 386 re
    f
    q
    8.33333 0 0 8.33333 0 0 cm
    BT
    /R8 9.96 Tf
    0 1.00057 -1 0 127.2 106.671 Tm
    [text 7] TJ
    0 1.00057 -1 0 138.24 60.3508 Tm
    [text 8] TJ
    ET
    Q
    1161 502.922 6 437 re
    f
    q
    8.33333 0 0 8.33333 0 0 cm
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    BT
    /R8 9.96 Tf
    0 1.00057 -1 0 138.24 112.791 Tm
    [line 1] TJ
    ET
    Q
    q
    1268 2621.92 m
    1268 2675.92 l
    1380 2675.92 l
    1380 2621.92 l
    h
    W
    n
    q
    8.33333 0 0 8.33333 0 0 cm
    BT
    /R9 11.04 Tf
    0 0.999402 -1 0 162.6 314.631 Tm
     Tj
    ET
    Q
    Q
    q
    1268 2621.92 m
    1268 4396.92 l
    2049 4396.92 l
    2049 2621.92 l
    h
    W
    n
    1 g
    1267 2620.92 780 1775 re
    f*
    Q
    q
    8.33333 0 0 8.33333 0 0 cm
    BT
    /R9 11.04 Tf
    0 0.999402 -1 0 204.6 515.751 Tm
     Tj
    ET
    Q
    0 0 1 RG
    0 0 1 rg
    q
    8.33333 0 0 8.33333 0 0 cm
    BT
    /R9 11.04 Tf
    0 0.999402 -1 0 227.16 355.071 Tm
    [line 2] TJ
    ET
    Q
    1903 2958.92 6 1101 re
    f
    0 G
    0 g
    q
    8.33333 0 0 8.33333 0 0 cm
    BT
    /R9 11.04 Tf
    0 0.999402 -1 0 227.16 487.191 Tm
     Tj
    ET
    Q
    q
    0 1565 -408 0 1705 2732.92 cm
    /X0 Do
    Q
    q
    0 1738 -506 0 2659 2639.92 cm
    /X1 Do
    Q
    q
    8.33333 0 0 8.33333 0 0 cm
    BT
    /R7 12 Tf
    0 1.00055 -1 0 342 398.991 Tm
    [line 3] TJ
    ET
```

I simplified TJ command to state only text. Please be aware that `Tj` is incorrectly displayed it is `<01> Tj` and you can see it in source when you try to edit question.

Page is rotated clockwise 90°. Page properties:

```
    [Type] => Page
    [MediaBox] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 595
            [3] => 842
        )

    [Rotate] => 90
    [Resources] => Array
        (
            [Font] => Array
                (
                    [R7] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => Helvetica-Bold
                            [Type] => Type1
                            [BaseFont] => Helvetica-Bold
                            [Subtype] => Type1
                        )

                    [R8] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => Helvetica
                            [Type] => Type1
                            [BaseFont] => Helvetica
                            [Subtype] => Type1
                        )

                    [R9] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => DUCRGK+Calibri
                            [Type] => TrueType
                            [BaseFont] => DUCRGK+Calibri
                            [FirstChar] => 1
                            [LastChar] => 18
                            [Subtype] => TrueType
                        )

                )

            [XObject] => Array
                (
                    [X0] => Array
                        (
                            [Subtype] => Image
                            [ColorSpace] => DeviceRGB
                            [Width] => 250
                            [Height] => 65
                            [BitsPerComponent] => 8
                            [Filter] => DCTDecode
                            [Length] => 3927
                        )

                    [X1] => Array
                        (
                            [Subtype] => Image
                            [ColorSpace] => DeviceRGB
                            [Width] => 278
                            [Height] => 81
                            [BitsPerComponent] => 8
                            [Filter] => FlateDecode
                            [Length] => 2617
                        )

                )

        )

    [Contents] => Array
        (
            [Filter] => FlateDecode
            [Length] => 2525
        )

    [Parent] => Array
        (
            [Type] => Pages
            [Count] => 20
        )
```

In PDF viewer it looks like:

```
    line 1
    image 1
    line 2
    image 2
    line 3
```

Because of page rotation `e Tx` and `f Ty` are switched.  And for example in `0 1.00057 -1 0 138.24 112.791 Tm` 138.24 is stating vertical shift and 112.791 horizontal.

For convenience I'll add also matrix representation here:

```
    [a b 0]
    [c d 0]
    [e f 1]

    or

    [a b c d e f]
```

It seems to be because of `cm` operator which states scaling image Tx and Ty are so big. Considering it we will have following results:

```
Ty           Content             Calculation
138.24       line 1
204,6        image 1             1705/8.33333
227.16       line 2
319,08       image 1             2659/8.33333
342          line 3
```

Which seems to be correct.

Transformations according to PDF reference v1.7 (Page 205):

> •Translations are specified as [ 1 0 0 1 tx ty ], where tx and ty are
>   the distances to translate the origin of the coordinate system in the
>   horizontal and vertical dimensions, respectively.
>
> •Scaling is obtained by [ sx 0 0 sy 0 0 ]. This scales the coordinates
>   so that 1 unit in the horizontal and vertical dimensions of the new
>   coordinate system is the same size as sx and sy units, respectively,
>   in the previous coordinate system.
>
> •Rotations are produced by [ cos θ sin θ −sin θ cos θ 0 0 ], which has
>   the effect of rotating the coordinate system axes by an angle θ
>   counterclockwise.
>
> •Skew is specified by [ 1 tan α tan β 1 0 0 ], which skews the x axis
>   by an angle α and the y axis by an angle β.

Questions:

1. Is matrix which `cm/Tm` operators change is same matrix? Meaning, after image processing and then modifying matrix for text with operator like `Td/TD` should it modify matrix after `cm` state?
2. Referencing to quote with transformation description. How to get known which of those transformation can be applied together with 1 command? For example for Scaling should there be only `sx` and `sy` stated and all other values are like in example 0, which identifies that it is scaling but 0 values should not be applied to actual matrix? It is evident that Skew + Rotation cannot be applied in 1 command as both of the uses `b` `c`. In same time Translations and Rotations is used together as I see in the example above.
3. In PDF reference it is stated that `Tm` replaces current matrix (Page 406) and `cm` concatenating (Page 219). Considering this my result is incorrect as along with `1705/8.33333` we should also add previous Ty position which is 138.24 and as result we will have 342,84 and it gives wrong Ty position. What is wrong here?
4. According to PDF reference v1.7 (Page 206) transformation is applied in following order: Translate, Rotate, Scale or skew. And I thought that scaling is applied to object itself not to the Tx and Ty positioning. So is that right what I'm doing `1705/8.33333` to identify image position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I answer your questions referencing the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) because the specification is an ISO norm while the PDF references have been called *not normative in nature* by Adobe staff.

> Is matrix which `cm/Tm` operators change is same matrix? Meaning, after image processing and then modifying matrix for text with operator like `Td/TD` should it modify matrix after `cm` state?

No, it is not the same matrix, and `cm` and `Tm` operate completely different.

**`cm`** manipulates the current transformation matrix (CTM), an element of the PDF graphics state, which defines the transformation from user space to device space. And it does so by multiplying the cm argument to the current value of the CTM, **not** by replacing the current value as is. *(Cf. section 8.3.2.3 - User Space - and Table 57 - Graphics State Operators - in the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*

As element of the PDF graphics state the CTM is subject to save and restore graphics state operators.

**`Tm`**, on the other hand, sets the text matrix, T<sub>m</sub>, and the text line matrix, T<sub>lm</sub> (it does **not** multiply its argument to the current value). T<sub>m</sub> in combination with the text state parameters T<sub>fs</sub>, T<sub>h</sub>, and T<sub>rise</sub> determine the transformation from text space to user space. *(Cf. section 9.4.4 - Text Space Details - and Table 108 - Text-positioning operators - in the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*

Furthermore, at the beginning of a text object, T<sub>m</sub> and T<sub>lm</sub> are reset to the identity matrix, and **`Td`** and **`TD`** modify these matrices. T<sub>m</sub> is advanced by text showing operators.

Conceptually, the entire transformation from text space to device space may be represented by a text rendering matrix, T<sub>rm</sub>

[image: The text rendering matrix]

And considering your question details, `Tm`, `TD`, `Td`, and all the other text related operators have no effect on the CTM.

> Referencing to quote with transformation description. How to get known which of those transformation can be applied together with 1 command? For example for Scaling should there be only `sx` and `sy` stated and all other values are like in example 0, which identifies that it is scaling but 0 values should not be applied to actual matrix? It is evident that Skew + Rotation cannot be applied in 1 command as both of the uses `b c`. In same time Translations and Rotations is used together as I see in the example above.

Any of those example transformations can be combined by simple matrix multiplication. As the text before those samples in the PDF specification states, *this sub-clause lists the arrays that specify the **most common** transformations*, it does **not** list **all** possible ones.

> In PDF reference it is stated that `Tm` replaces current matrix (Page 406) and `cm` concatenating (Page 219). Considering this my result is incorrect as along with `1705/8.33333` we should also add previous Ty position which is 138.24 and as result we will have 342,84 and it gives wrong Ty position. What is wrong here?

In your analysis you ignored the operators **q** and **Q** which simply cannot be ignored for a proper result.

- The **q** operator pushes a copy of the entire graphics state onto the Graphics State stack.
- The **Q** operator restores the entire graphics state to its former value by popping it from the stack.

As the CTM is part of the graphics state, **Q** replaces the CTM with the value stored at the time of the corresponding **q**. *(Cf. section 8.4.2 - Graphics State Stack - in the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*

Thus, you have to take this into account. If we do, we get the following progression of active CTM and CTMs on the graphics state stack. As we are interested in coordinates in the default user space coordinate system (i.e. relative to the **MediaBox** `[0 0 595 842]` which due to the **Rotate** value `90` is oriented to have rising **x** coordinates going down and rising **y** coordinates going right), we start with the identity matrix as CTM value:

```
****CTM: [1 0 0 1 0 0]
****Stack: -
q
****CTM: [1 0 0 1 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0]
0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0 cm
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0]
1 g
472 471.922 4014 6073 re
f
0 G
0 g
q
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
8.33333 0 0 8.33333 0 0 cm
****CTM: [1 0 0 1 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
BT
/R7 12 Tf
0 1.00055 -1 0 71.52 336.711 Tm
[text 1] TJ
/R8 9.96 Tf
0 1.00057 -1 0 105.12 60.3506 Tm
[text 2] TJ
ET
Q
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0]
885 502.922 6 297 re
f
q
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
8.33333 0 0 8.33333 0 0 cm
****CTM: [1 0 0 1 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
BT
/R8 9.96 Tf
0 1.00057 -1 0 105.12 95.9906 Tm
[text 3] TJ
0 1.00057 -1 0 116.16 60.3505 Tm
[text 4] TJ
ET
Q
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0]
977 502.922 6 535 re
f
q
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
8.33333 0 0 8.33333 0 0 cm
****CTM: [1 0 0 1 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
BT
/R8 9.96 Tf
0 1.00057 -1 0 116.16 124.551 Tm
[text 5] TJ
0 1.00057 -1 0 127.2 60.3507 Tm
[text 6] TJ
ET
Q
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0]
1069 502.922 6 386 re
f
q
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
8.33333 0 0 8.33333 0 0 cm
****CTM: [1 0 0 1 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
BT
/R8 9.96 Tf
0 1.00057 -1 0 127.2 106.671 Tm
[text 7] TJ
0 1.00057 -1 0 138.24 60.3508 Tm
[text 8] TJ
ET
Q
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0]
1161 502.922 6 437 re
f
q
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
8.33333 0 0 8.33333 0 0 cm
****CTM: [1 0 0 1 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
BT
/R8 9.96 Tf
0 1.00057 -1 0 138.24 112.791 Tm
[line 1] TJ
ET
Q
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0]
q
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
1268 2621.92 m
1268 2675.92 l
1380 2675.92 l
1380 2621.92 l
h
W
n
q
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
8.33333 0 0 8.33333 0 0 cm
****CTM: [1 0 0 1 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
BT
/R9 11.04 Tf
0 0.999402 -1 0 162.6 314.631 Tm
<01> Tj
ET
Q
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
Q
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0]
q
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
1268 2621.92 m
1268 4396.92 l
2049 4396.92 l
2049 2621.92 l
h
W
n
1 g
1267 2620.92 780 1775 re
f*
Q
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0]
q
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
8.33333 0 0 8.33333 0 0 cm
****CTM: [1 0 0 1 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
BT
/R9 11.04 Tf
0 0.999402 -1 0 204.6 515.751 Tm
<01> Tj
ET
Q
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0]
0 0 1 RG
0 0 1 rg
q
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
8.33333 0 0 8.33333 0 0 cm
****CTM: [1 0 0 1 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
BT
/R9 11.04 Tf
0 0.999402 -1 0 227.16 355.071 Tm
[line 2] TJ
ET
Q
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0]
1903 2958.92 6 1101 re
f
0 G
0 g
q
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
8.33333 0 0 8.33333 0 0 cm
****CTM: [1 0 0 1 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
BT
/R9 11.04 Tf
0 0.999402 -1 0 227.16 487.191 Tm
<01> Tj
ET
Q
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0]
q
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
0 1565 -408 0 1705 2732.92 cm
****CTM: [0 187.8 -48.96 0 204.6 327.95]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
/X0 Do
Q
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0]
q
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
0 1738 -506 0 2659 2639.92 cm
****CTM: [0 208.56 -60.72 0 319.08 316.79]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
/X1 Do
Q
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0]
q
****CTM: [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
8.33333 0 0 8.33333 0 0 cm
****CTM: [1 0 0 1 0 0]
****Stack: [1 0 0 1 0 0] [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]
BT
/R7 12 Tf
0 1.00055 -1 0 342 398.991 Tm
[line 3] TJ
ET
```

If you prefer coordinates in the rotated default user space coordinate system (i.e. in the rectangle `[0 -595 842 0]` which is the **MediaBox** `[0 0 595 842]` rotated clockwise by 90° around the origin), you have to multiply the matrices above from the right by `[0 -1 1 0 0 0]`.

For the CTMs used for the images this in particular means:

```
****CTM: [187.8 0 0 48.96 327.95 -204.6]
****Stack: [0 -1  1 0 0 0] [0 -0.12 0.12 0 0 0]
/X0 Do
...
****CTM: [208.56 0 0 60.72 316.79 -319.08]
****Stack: [0 -1  1 0 0 0] [0 -0.12 0.12 0 0 0]
/X1 Do
```

> According to PDF reference v1.7 (Page 206) transformation is applied in following order: Translate, Rotate, Scale or skew. And I thought that scaling is applied to object itself not to the Tx and Ty positioning. So is that right what I'm doing `1705/8.33333` to identify image position?

The specification more exactly says: *If several transformations are combined, the order in which they are applied is significant. For example, first scaling and then translating the x axis is not the same as first translating and then scaling it. **In general, to obtain the expected results, transformations should be done in the following order: Translate, Rotate, Scale or skew.***

This is a *recommendation*, *not a requirement*, and it is merely meant to make the life of PDF creators easier. With some Linear Algebra knowledge one knows how to multiply matrices and what to expect regardless of the order, keeping to the recommended order merely makes things easier to understand.

Concerning your *thought that scaling is applied to object itself not to the Tx and Ty positioning*: The current transformation matrix (including any scaling in it) is applied to anything you do in the user space; usually, though, objects are located or anchored at the origin (0,0) of the current user coordinate system, and the origin is the fixed point of all pure scaling transformations. Thus, scaling wont change that location / anchor point.

Comment: I added back all operators in command sequence. Could you please help me with calculations?

Comment: @Index *I added back all operators in command sequence.* - There is something missing up front, or else the operator sequence is broken. Please add those missing parts, otherwise I cannot properly do the calculations. Furthermore, some properties of the page (immediate or inherited) also are of interest, foremost rotation (ok, you mentioned the 90°) and the media- and cropbox.

Comment: Add page properties and operator sequence from beginning. Also added note that `Tj` is incorrectly displayed it looses values. In source if you try to edit it should look like: <01> Tj

Comment: @Index I edited my answer to contain your content stream with actual CTMs and CTMs on the graphics state stack.

Comment: it turns out that I do not understand how to multiply, concatenate matrices and what is the difference between multiply and concatenating (stated for `cm` operator). Tried to multiply matrices `[0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]` and `0 1738 -506 0 2659 2639.92` as 3x3 matrices and got following result `[0 208,68 -60,72 0 2659 2639,9]`. Could you please provide description on how you perform multiplication/concatenation. Link to web page with description would be fine. Like for example this one http://ncalculators.com/matrix/3x3-matrix-multiplication-calculator.htm which describes 3x3 multiplication.

Comment: It is important to remember that matrix multiplication is not commutative, the order is important. And **cm** operates by right multiplication on the existing CTM. Thus, you have to calculate `[0 1738 -506 0 2659 2639.92] × [0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0]`.

Comment: Arg! I wrote "by right multiplication" but of course it's left multiplication. Sigh.